# SQLCipher Android and hexkey encryption

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher

I've created an encrypted database using C#-SQLite after reading that it was compatible with SQLCipher. I'm using the following command to encrypt:

```
PRAGMA hexkey="0x0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F01";
```

I'm attempting to open the file using SQLCipher by creating a char array of the key and converting to String to use as the password as follows:

```
private static final char[] DB_KEY = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x01 };

String password = new String(DB_KEY);

mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbPath, password, null);
```

This throws an exception that the database is not a database or encrypted.

Firstly, I would like to confirm that the encryption is even compatible with SQLCipher as this is information I got from a StackOverflow question and if I'm barking up the wrong tree I'll move on.

If it is compatible, what am I doing wrong with the decryption?

Comment: you define `DB_KEY`, but then use `MAP_KEY` for `password`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

The format you are using is not correct for a raw hex key.  To use a raw hex key within SQLCipher you must format your string such that it is prefixed with an x followed by a single quote, then a 64 character hex string and terminated with a single quote.  A `PRAGMA` statement might look something like this:

```
PRAGMA key = "x'2DD29CA851E7B56E4697B0E1F08507293D761A05CE4D1B628663F411A8086D99'";
```

In the event of using SQLCipher for Android, your String might look something like this:

```
String key = "x\'2DD29CA851E7B56E4697B0E1F08507293D761A05CE4D1B628663F411A8086D99\'";
```